# Find a key if a value exists in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working with Python 3.6 and I need to loop through the nested dictionary to find if a specified value exists, and if so, store all keys that correspond to that value. I also need to expand these criteria to be able to store keys for which the specified value exists for a specified sub-dictionary key.

The dictionary is built as below:

```
dict = {A: {B: [a, b, c], C: [d, c, e]}, D: {B: [f, g, h], E: [i, j, c]}...}
```

Each primary key (A, D etc.) is unique, but the keys in the sub-dictionaries repeat in different sub-dictionaries.

I would like to get all the primary keys for which a value such as "c" exists, so the output would be:

```
foundKeys = [A, D]
```

I would also like to add criteria for a sub-dictionary key, so e.g. get all primary keys for which "c" exists for "B" sub-dictionary key. Here the output would be:

```
foundKeys = [A]
```

As for the first condition, I came up with the code below:

```
myList = list(dict.keys())

foundKeys = []

for i in range(0,len(myList)):
    tmpList = list(dict.get(myList[i],{}).values())
    for j in range(0, len(tmpList)):
        for k in range(0, len(tmpList[j])):
            if "c" in tmpList[j][k]:
                if myList[i] not in foundKeys:
                    foundKeys.append(myList[i])
```

This allows me to get a list of all the keys that have corresponding value "c" ([A,D]), but I have a large dataset and I realize that there is probably a better way to handle this.

I could alter this code to add the sub-dictionary key condition and get the output [A], but it would take even more time to run it.

I'm new to Python and still learning how to optimize. Can you advise how can I approach this to better handle it when dealing with a large dataset?

Answer (score 3):

You are looping over all elements in you dictionary structure. You should break the loop as soon as soon as you have found an occurrence. Here is a one-liner using list comprehension:

```
d = {'A': {'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'C': ['d', 'c', 'e']}, 'D': {'B': ['f', 'g', 'h'], 'E': ['i', 'j', 'c']}}

found_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if any("c" in l for l in v.values())]
```

If you want to filter by a subdictionary key, it's even shorter:

```
found_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if "c" in v['B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt `.keys()` and `.values()` to directly fetch the keys and values respectively.

**Code:**

```
dict = {'A': {'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'C': ['d', 'c', 'e']}, 'D': {'B': ['f', 'g', 'h'], 'E': ['i', 'j', 'c']}}

listOfKeys = []
for i in dict.keys():
    for j in dict[i].values():
        if 'c' in j:
            if i not in listOfKeys:
                listOfKeys.append(i)

print(listOfKeys)
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it more shortly with something like this:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for key, subdict in d.items():
...     for sublist in subdict.values():
...         if "c" in sublist:
...             result.append(key)
...             break
... 
>>> print(result)
['A', 'D']
```

Note the use of `items` and `values` as ways to iterate over the elements of a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to perform a lot of lookups of this sort, a little pre-processing will go a long way.

Take the dictionary you presented in your question:

```
dict = { A: { B: [a, b, c] 
            , C: [d, c, e]
            } 
       , D: { B: [f, g, h]
            , E: [i, j, c]
            }
       }
```

You could go through each key-value pair and construct something like

```
new_dict = { a: { A: {B, C}
                , D: {E}
                }
           , b: { A: {B} 
                }
           , c: { A: {B, C}
                , D: {E}
                } 
           , d: { A: {C}
                }
           , e: { A: {C}
                }
           , f: { D: {B}
                }
           , g: { D: {B}
                }
           , h: { D: {B}
                }
           , i: { D: {E}
                }
           , j: { D: {E}
                }
           }
```

In the dictionary above, each of the values from the original dictionary
`dict` is a key. Each of these is associated with its own dictionary where the keys are the top-level keys from the original dictionary and the values are sets of keys from sub-dictionaries.

It may be a lot of work up-front, but it ought to save you time when you're performing repeated searches of the kind you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to handle input of arbitrary depth:

```
d1 = {'A': {'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'C': ['d', 'c', 'e']}, 'D': {'B': ['f', 'g', 'h'], 'E': ['i', 'j', 'c']}}
def get_keys(d, to_find):
  for a, b in d.items():
     if to_find in b:
       yield a
     if isinstance(b, dict):
       yield from get_keys(b, to_find)

print(list(get_keys(d1, 'c')))
```

Output:

```
['B', 'C', 'E']
```